# VBA pivot table calculate field, then summarise it

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a data series which looks like this:

```
Cell Nam    HSDPA User Capacity (Kbps)
68693A  number
68693A  number
68693A  number
68693B  number
68693B  number
68693B  number
68693C  number
68693C  number
68693C  number
```

What I want to do is create a pivot table using VBA, to first turn "HSDPA User capacity into Mbps" (by didiving it by 1000), and then to return the average for each "Cell Nam"

Currently I am using the following code:

```
'Creating Pivot table
    Set objPivotTable = objPivotcache.CreatePivotTable(tempRange)

    'Setting Fields
    With objPivotTable

        'set row field
        With .PivotFields("Cell Nam")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        'set calculated fields
        .CalculatedFields.Add "HSDPA User Capacity (Mbps)", "='HSDPA User Capacity (kbps)'/1000"

        'set data fields
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("HSDPA User Capacity (Mbps)"), "Average of HSDPA User Capacity (Mbps)", xlAverage
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("HSDPA User Capacity (Mbps)"), "Min of HSDPA User Capacity (Mbps)", xlMin

    End With
```

**But instead of returning the average and min of my calculated field, it just return the sum**

Any idea how to solve this?

PS: When I just use the original field (before dividing by 1000) everything works fine by using the below code

```
.AddDataField .PivotFields("HSDPA User Capacity (kbps)"), "Average of HSDPA User Capacity (kbps)", xlAverage
.AddDataField .PivotFields("HSDPA User Capacity (kbps)"), "Min of HSDPA User Capacity (kbps)", xlMin
```

Comment: Is it too much to divide source range column by 1,000? I could be wrong but can you even do what you ask using Excel UI?